# log4j failure - Failed to flush writer in servlet (java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor)

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

Log4J is failing for us generally after a few hours of use in our servlet environment (tomcat 7.0.26 running on CentOS 5.5 with Java 1.6u31). After this error occurs no further logging happens until the tomcat is restarted. Another really weird thing is that sometimes the logging requests are flushed out to jsps that are served up.  There will be about 10 lines or so of logging then the html page below it. We are using the latest log4j jar.

These logs are from the catalina.out. Our application specific logs just stop.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
        ...

log4j:ERROR Could not close org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter@1e7abbd
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterWriter.close(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Just a guess... is there any space left on the disk?

Comment: Yea there is plenty of disk space.

Comment: Is this a Unix based OS?

Comment: Yea sorry @Sean, I've edited my post to note we are running CentOS 5.5.

Comment: [This post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.log4j.user/13515) suggests they had conflicting 3rd party jars. Any chances you having the same issue?

Comment: @mindas it's definitely possible as we use quite a few 3rd party jars. I've switched us to using logback instead of log4j as it's been recommended in quite a few posts here as a better alternative to log4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the underlying cause of our problems was. I switched from log4j to [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and haven't had any problems since.

They even have a nice [converter](http://logback.qos.ch/translator/) to convert log4j.properties files into their logback equivalent so it was pretty easy to switch.